# Inserting a std::vector as returned from a function

Tags: c++, vector

I find myself frequently doing something like this to concatenate several vectors that are returned from functions (possibly class functions):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> v1;

const vector<int>& F1() {
    cout << "F1 was called" << endl;
    /*Populate v1, which may be an expensive operation*/
    return v1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> Concat;
    Concat.insert(Concat.end(), F1().begin(), F1().end());
    /*Do something with Concat*/
    return 0;
}
```

As I expected, `F1()` is called twice, which may be undesirable if it is an expensive function call.  An alternative is to copy the return value of `F1()` into a temporary vector which would only require one function call, but would incur a copy operation which might be undesirable if the vector is large.  The only other alternative I can think of is to create a pointer to a temporary vector and assign the return value of `F1()` to it like this:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> Concat;
    const vector<int>* temp = &F1();
    Concat.insert(Concat.end(), temp->begin(), temp->end());
    /*Do something with Concat*/
    return 0;
}
```

Is this really the best solution?  The use of a temporary variable seems cumbersome, especially if I need to concatenate several vectors.  I also feel like there should be a way to do this using references instead of pointers.  Any suggestions?

Comment: " I also feel like there should be a way to do this using references instead of pointers." there is. Just use reference.

Comment: If I use references by changing `const vector<int>* temp = &F1();` to `const vector<int>& temp = F1();`, will this incur a copy operation on the vector?

Comment: Only one. When you insert it the vector must be copied to the end of the Concat (and probably a realocation will occur).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is not to use `vector` directly in the first place but `OutputIterator`s and `std::back_inserter`.

```
template <typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator F1( OutputIterator out )
{
    cout << "F1 was called" << endl;
    /* Insert stuff via *out++ = ...; */
    *out++ = 7;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> Concat;
    // perhaps reserve some moderate amount of storage to avoid reallocation

    F1( std::back_inserter(Concat) );
    F1( std::back_inserter(Concat) );
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/40rBWH).
This way maximum efficiency and flexibility are achieved.

Comment: Can you add how this works?

Comment: This addresses the original question, but is still not a generally satisfying solution. In some cases one might just want to append the returned vector of an existing function that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this really the best solution?

No. `std::vector` supports move semantics, so you should do this instead:

```
vector<int> F1() // return by value
{
    std::vector<int> v1; // locally declared here
    cout << "F1 was called" << endl;
    /*Populate v1, which may be an expensive operation*/
    return v1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> Concat;
    auto v2 = F1(); // create local variable and assign result of F1
    Concat.insert(Concat.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    /*Do something with Concat*/
    return 0;
}
```

This code:

- doesn't depend on global variables defined elsewhere
- is efficient (`F1()` gets called *once*)
- is simple and straightforward

**Edit**: On second thought, go with @Columbo's approach. It is more idiomatic, more flexible, and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I agree, this is very straightforward and easy to read.  In some cases I'm returning a vector which is a private class member, so I don't think I can use move semantics in that case unfortunately.

Comment: No, in such a case (private member) it usually doesn't make sense to return by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> F1() {
    cout << "F1 was called" << endl;
    vector<int> v1;
    /*Populate v1, which may be an expensive operation*/
    return v1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> Concat;
    vector<int> v1 = F1();
    Concat.insert(Concat.end(), v1.begin(), v2.end());
    /*Do something with Concat*/
    return 0;
}
```

this will be even faster than your original code. 
Returning a vector shouldn't copy it in C++11, you're guaranteed that if movable, it will be moved. Moreover in this particular case NRVO (Namer return value optimization) will kick in.

However I would do it this way:

```
void F1(vector<int>& v1) {
    cout << "F1 was called" << endl;
    /*Populate v1, which may be an expensive operation*/
    return;
}
```

and you just concatenate directly into v1 in the method.

Comment: Thanks.  The general consensus seems to be to pass the vector to the function instead of inserting the return value into the vector.